# Javascript function only works on the first call

Tags: javascript, php

I'm developing a Question&Answer website in php and I want to print the answer comments when I press the button. Everything works like a charm but only on the first button. I have an idea why this does't work, I guess it only takes into account the first id that it finds.

So , my question is, is there any way to name the element I want to call based on its id? For example:

```
<button class="btn icon-chat" title="Add a comment on this answer"
                        type="button" id="showarea . {answer['answerid']"} name="showarea" value="Show Textarea">
                    Comment</button>
<div id="textarea">
                    {include file="comment_form.tpl"}
                </div>
```

But how would I call this PHP variable on my JS function?

```
$("#textarea, #textarea-ok").hide(); // or you can have hidden w/ CSS
$("#showarea").click(function(){
    $("#textarea").show();
});
$("#textarea-ok, #cancel").click(function(){
    $("#textarea").hide();
});
```

Is this the best approach? Any advise regarding to the JS code you can give?

Kind Regards

Comment: "id" values cannot contain spaces and they should not contain "." characters unless you want to make your life more difficult

Comment: what do you think this id would be `id="showarea . {answer['answerid']"}` ? There's at least 5 things wrong with that!!! also, #textarea and #showarea etc is selecting elements with id="textarea" or "showarea" ... they don't appear to be in the markup you've shown

Comment: I meant concatenate the name of the id with the answer id. I didnt mean to put spaces or characters. That was misleading.

Comment: the code has 5 different **ID** selectors ... your HTML has one ID that most likely ends up completely different to what you think (due to the misplaced " and } - and even if you fix that, the ID would be 4 types of wrong

Comment: `I meant concatenate` - HTML doesn't work like that - was that supposed to be done by PHP?

Comment: Added the textarea div @JaromandaX

Comment: @LuísCosta - irrelevant - your ID is wrong, your selectors still make no sense with respect to the HTML shown ... e.g. you have a button with `name="showarea"` ... do you think that's selected using `$('#showarea')` ? your `<button` also has a `type='button'` - why? can a `<button>` be something else?

Comment: is `{ some content }` a new way of using php or something? do things in `{}` get preprocessed by PHP now? (been years since I cared about PHP)

Answer (score 3):

Live method should be ok

```
$("body").on("click", ".myClass", function(){
    // do it again // or #myId
});
```

Don't forget about an event with an Id selector can be only on one element, and class on every one...

Edit with example

```
<div class="post-button clearfix">
    // i changed this button as well
    <button class="btn icon-chat show-textarea" title="Add a comment on this answer" type="button" data-answer="{$answer['publicationid']}">Comment</button>

    <div class="textarea">
        {include file="comment_form.tpl"}
    </div>
</div>


// comment_form.tpl

// i added a master container
<div class="comment-form">
    <form method="post" action="{$BASE_URL}controller/actions/comments/create_comment.php">
        <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="40" class="qa-form-tall-text"></textarea>

        // i deleted the wrong input here
        <input type="hidden" name="answerid" value="{$answer['answerid']}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="{$question['publicationid']}" />

        // i changed these 2 buttons as well
        <button type="button" class="textarea-cancel qa-form-tall-button qa-form-tall-button-comment">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="textarea-ok">Ok</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then you change the script with class in selector like :

```
...

$('.comment-form').hide();

$("body").on("click", ".show-textarea", function(){
    $('.comment-form').show();
});

$("body").on("click", ".textarea-ok, .textarea-cancel", function(){
    $('.comment-form').hide();
});

....
```

More about Jquery Selector : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

More about live method wit .on() :
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

More about Html forms
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Read these docs to be ok with yourself ;)

Comment: actually, jquery will work with multiple identical id's (as will querySelectorAll for that matter)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Should I name my button class , ".myClass"?

Comment: no @LuísCosta ... the `.` in the selector means you want a class, so `class='myClass'` would be selected using `$('.myClass')` - just as `id='uniqueId'` is selected using `$('#uniqueId')` - the `#`, `.` (and `+` and `>` amongst others) have specific meaning in the selector string, not in the class/id etc itself

Comment: Also, why would the `live` method be required as there's no evidence of dynamic content

Comment: Alright, thank you. But I still didnt get where I should add the `class="showarea" data-answer="yourAnswerId"`. Is it on my button?

Comment: @LuísCosta - it could be ... you've shown very little of your markup, you've referred to 5 different ID's and shown one malformed ID, so, who knows

Comment: it's evident Luis searching to add some comment in the DOM dynamically ;)

Comment: you add the arg data-answer to find again the probable targeted comment you would modify or whatever... i anticipated this fact ;)

Comment: data-answer works like an Index, and if you want to target it, you could do it easily with $(".showarea[data-answer='yourAnswerId']")

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working. Now it doesn't even hide the textarea anymore :\

Comment: Edit your post with the entire html ... i ll correct it fast

Comment: Here it is! Thank you so much! @Pirs https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58242703925f94c90ad9706b9c455304

Comment: Luis i need to know comment_form.tpl to be ok

Comment: I'm sorry @Pirs , just got home. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c853ee63a607df27ebedb1d907228048